# blazor monitor all keyup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Using jquery we can use the $(document).ready function to monitor all textarea keyboard events on the page and update their text counter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("textarea").keyup(function () {
    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currLength = $(this).val().length;
    var spanid = $(this).attr("id") + "_counter";
    $("#" + spanid).val(maxLength - currLength);
    });
});
```

But in blazor the document.ready does not work. After some research I found discussion about using `OnAfterRenderAsync` to achieve the same effect. The problem is, in this way, each textarea needs to be wired up individually. I'm hoping to find a way similar to the jquery method, so as long as I lay some scripts on the page it can handle additional stuff I throw onto the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to implement `blazor keyup event` or want to use `(document).ready` we can use `KeyboardEvent` to pick `keyup` or `keypress` event and yes we have to use `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Comment: You even can use @bind property to calculate counter on the fly.